# Is there any trick to make the code only run when hydrating html

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, server-side-rendering

There are three situations when react ssr

- Server-side rendering
- Client-side Hydrating
- Normal client-side rendering

Just like using `typeof window === 'undefined'` to make the code run only on the server side, is there any trick to make the code run only on the second situation ?

```
const useSomething = () => {
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
        // when ssr
    }
    if ( ??? ) {
        // when client-side Hydrating
    }
    // client-side rendering
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with SSR in React applications, there are three situations (like you mentioned) where the code can be executed: during server-side rendering, during client-side hydration, and during normal client-side rendering.

1. During server-side rendering, the JavaScript code is executed on the server, where window is not defined, that's why `typeof window === 'undefined'` works to detect that.
2. When the application is loaded on the client, the server-generated HTML is rendered in the browser, and the JavaScript code is executed again. This time, window is defined, but the application's state needs to be hydrated with the data passed from the server. The window.**INITIAL_STATE** object contains the initial state values that were passed from the server.

So, to detect whether the code is running during client-side hydration, you can check if window.**INITIAL_STATE** is defined.

Here's how you can check for that

```
const useSomething = () => {
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    // We're in server-side rendering
  } else if (window.__INITIAL_STATE__) {
    // We're in client-side hydration
  } else {
    // We're in normal client-side rendering
  }`
};
```